# Method in session scoped bean returns null for non-null field

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-6, servlet-filters

When I am trying to get the value from the bean (annotated `@SessionScoped`) using method `getContractNumber()` I am getting `null`. However, when directly accessing the field `parameters.contractNumber` the result is the correct value from request. I understand that JavaEE is proxying my bean object and in this case I would have expected the reversed effect. How can I access my bean field value? I don't want to use the field directly.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank;


public class InitialRequestParametersFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    private Provider<InitialRequestParameters> parameters;

    @SessionScoped
    public static class InitialRequestParameters implements Serializable {
        private String contractNumber = null;

        InitialRequestParameters() {}

        private void setContractNumber(String contractNumber) {
            this.contractNumber = contractNumber;
        }

        public Optional<String> getContractNumber() {
            return Optional.fromNullable(contractNumber);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String contractNumberFromRequest = servletRequest.getParameter("contractno");
        if(isNotBlank(contractNumberFromRequest)) {
            parameters.get().setContractNumber(contractNumberFromRequest);
        }
        // this returns the request parameter
        System.out.println(parameters.get().contractNumber);
        // this returns Optional.absent() !!!
        System.out.println(parameters.get().getContractNumber());
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: hm. just a guess, but when you create bean from class that has interface, it will create proxy. Proxy will ONLY override methods that are declared in interfaces that the class implements. Methods that are not declared will return null or default value, normally. So, try to have it declare interface or remove the interface of serializable so that it can instantiate it with CGLIB to actually have code from your class.

Comment: `provider.get()` creates a new object for every call. Thus, call it *once*, assign the result to a variable and reuse it.